# Fetching data from intermediate table

Tags: mysql, jakarta-ee, ejb-3.0

I created database tables Formation, formateur, and formateur_formation (MySQL).
And formateur_formation table (intermediate table) contains the formation_id and formateur_id .
Formation and formateur relationship is many to many.
I want to retrieve data in formateur_formation table but the problem is that table is not an entity .
I use EJB 3.0

Comment: i tried to fetch column but the problem is that table is not an entity ,

Answer (score 0):

Finally i find the solution

```
String SQL = "select * from formation_formateur"; 
Query q=em.createNativeQuery(SQL);
List<Object[]> listResults = q.getResultList();
```